# Query array values in cosmos collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am new to cosmos db and I have done a lot of SQL. I would like to know how can I query cosmos collection properties that is an array.

For example:

Cosmos Data

```
    "id": "123",
    "addressArray": {
        "date": null,
        "type": "Home",
        "addresses": [
            {
                "type": "ALL",
                "city": "London"
            },
            {
                "type": "City",
                "city": "Paris"
            },
            {
                "type": "City",
                "city": "New York"
            }
        ],
        "Use": null
    }
```

Now I want to write a query in cosmos to find addresses in Paris and New York where Type is city

```
Select * from c where c.addressArray.addresses[0] = "New York"
```

What should be the query when there is an array?

Comment: Have you looked at self-joins? Seems like that would cover this requirement...

Comment: Check out this article. Will show you how to write a query for this array. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this?

```
SELECT value city
FROM Games g 
JOIN city IN g.addressArray.addresses
WHERE city.city = 'New York' OR city.city='Paris'
```